# リストの中身を計算後の値を元にsortしたい

Tags: python

Pythonで以下のように、num_listがあって、これをsortすると、普通にsortできます。

```
num_list = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]
num_list = sorted(num_list)
print(num_list)
#result:[0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]
```

num_listを元に、以下のように2次関数の計算をした場合calc_num_listの中身の順番は、num_listとは異なった順番になります。
この計算結果の順番をもとに、元のnum_listをsortをするにはどうするのが良いでしょうか？

```
import math
num_list = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]
calc_num_list = []
for num in num_list:
    calc_num = -1 * num * num + num + 0.5
    calc_num_list .append(calc_num)
print(calc_num_list )
#result:[0.59, 0.66, 0.75, 0.5, -1.5, -5.5, -19.5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sorted](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions)関数のキーに計算処理を入れることでソートできます。

```
num_list = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]
sorted_by_calc = sorted(num_list, key=lambda num: (-1 * num * num + num + 0.5))
print(sorted_by_calc)
#[5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

NumPy 使う方法もあります

```py
import numpy as np
#result:[0.59, 0.66, 0.75, 0.5, -1.5, -5.5, -19.5]

ind = np.argsort(calc_num_list)
# print(np.take_along_axis(np.array(num_list), ind, axis=0))

# 一次元なので, こちらでも OK
print(np.array(num_list)[ind])
# [5.  3.  2.  1.  0.1 0.2 0.5]
```